# magento shopping cart price rule not working

Tags: magento

[image]

I don't understand why is this rule not working? If I change "total quantity equals or greater than" from 1 (visible as TRUE) to 0 (visible as FALSE), the rule applies to every single product in the shop instead of just chosen categories. This rule used to work before until expiry date. After it expired I've moved the expiry date into future, but the rule wouldn't work. I've tried creating a new rule with same conditions, no luck. Any suggestions?

Comment: Isn't the rule supposed to be compared to a number? Like "Total Items Quantity  equals or greater than  100"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Apparently, categories I've selected were nesting other categories and it doesn't work that way. You have to select all categories with products in them.